# Zend_Dom_Query how to get html code of current node

Tags: php, zend-dom-query

I have nodes, and iterate them in loop.

```
$html = <<<HTML
    <div id="test">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    </div>
HTML;
$dom= new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
$results = $dom->query('span');
foreach($results as $node){
...
}
```

How get html code of node? (not innerHTML, full HTML code `<span>1</span>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$htmlNode = iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1',$results->getDocument()->saveXML($node));
```

Iconv exist here because i have russian characters.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently working on Zend_Dom_Query. Was having a very hard time to figure this out. Finally got the solution. So this answer is for those still struggling out there.

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
$results = $dom->query('div#test');
foreach($results as $node){
    if($node->hasChildnodes()) {
        $childNodes = $node->childNodes;
        $countOfNodes = $childNodes->length;
        $firstSpan = $childNodes->item(0)->C14N();
    }
}
```

`$firstSpan` will contain `<span>1</span>`. You can also loop through the nodes using `$countOfNodes` to get 2nd span or nth element

Please check [PHP:DOMElement - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) and [PHP:DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) for more info.

Comment: That's good, but question was about how get <span>1</span>, selecting div#test span.

Comment: You mean you want the content of the span element? You need value 1 of first span?

Comment: No, i needs <span>1</span>